# disabling the screen on windows 8/10?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

I am trying to do, pretty much what the topic says on windows 8 and 10. I've tried "nircmd", and there was also a small trick I used in 7 by typing "displayswitch /external", equivalent of pressing windows+p and scrolling to second screen only. That used a virtual display that in theory wasn't actually connected, but windows didn't seem to care, giving me nothing but black screen and no visual content. Well in new versions of windows, this is not possible. At least not on the computers I've tried. Nircmd works, but once I press a button, the screen just comes back to life, and that's not what needs to be accomplished. Can anyone recommend a method of going about this, but in a way that I am still able to do everything, pressing keys, hearing audio, etc.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but WIN+P is normally used to move the view to a projector. Pressing it a few times could disable the main display and only use an external display. press WIN+P again to revert back. You may need to press ENTER to confirm your selection though.

Answer (score -1):

The way I have always done it is press Windows+p,  scroll down to second screen only with arrows, press enter, and if prompted, press enter on “keep the changes” button. If you wish to see if it staid on the second screen only, just get into the projecting window again by pressing windows+p and the second screen only should be selected by default. To switch back, get into the window again,  scroll to pc screen only, and press enter. this time you shouldn't need to confirm that you wish to keep the changes.  I am not aware of any other way to do this.